# Msal Azure AD -> redirect to azure login screen

Tags: reactjs, azure

we are using react with azure AD ,
and i wanted to understand how the refresh token works .
when user's session expire i want be redirected to. microsoft azure login page ..
can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

OK so.... what i found is this :

you need to use Msal hook in order to initiate the instance and the account data.

```
    const {instance, accounts} = useMsal();
```

there a a few tokens that are save in session storage on the browser .

1. access token = when expire we need to  use the following :

   ```
   await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                ...loginRequest,
                account: accounts[0]
            }
   ```

loginRequest = you can take the value from you MSAL config file (it's actually the scope)
account is the account of the user

2.refreshToken - it's microsoft 24 hours token ,  when expired or when error occur in the silent token - you can redirect to login screen and ask the user to enter credentials again - and a new token will be generated .

```
 await instance.acquireTokenRedirect({
        ...loginRequest,
        prompt: 'login',
    })
```

loginRequest = you can take the value from you MSAL config file (it's actually the scope)
prompt: login will tell microsoft to redirect to sign-in page .(it can be your own sign in or default)

I hope it makes sense to you all,
and i hope it helps someone.

I hope it helped.
took me some time to figure it out .
if you need more info write me

Answer (score 0):

Oded Kessler - mate you helped me immensely.

I am using angular with MSAL to authenticate agains B2C. In my case access and refresh tokens expired and I was getting:

AADB2C90077: User does not have an existing session and request prompt parameter has a value of 'None'.

To fix it I did following:

```
this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$
  .pipe(
    filter(
      (msg: EventMessage) =>
        msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_FAILURE ||
        msg.eventType === EventType.ACQUIRE_TOKEN_FAILURE
    ),
    takeUntil(this._destroying$)
  )
  .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
    if (result.error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {

      const redirectRequest: RedirectRequest = {
        scopes: [web_app_clientId],
        authority: YOUR_POLICY_URL,
        prompt: 'login',
      };

      this.msalService.instance.acquireTokenRedirect(redirectRequest);
    }
  });
```